# Create association data from data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data in a data table that looks like this:

```
Category  Country
A         India
B         Canada
C         Ireland
A         Ireland
C         Canada
A         India
A         Canada
```

I want to transform it so that if a country produces the same 2 categories then the there is a row in the resulting data table with the name of the country and the name of the two categories. So, the output of the above should look like:

```
Value 1   Value 2  Country
A         A        India
B         C        Canada
B         A        Canada
C         A        Canada
C         A        Ireland
```

Presently I am converting it into a matrix and plan on converting it into a long format:

```
M=(as.matrix( table(df) ) )
```

But that will just gives me a summary of my desired output where instead of getting separate rows for each *Category1, Category2, Country* value, I will get *Category1, Category2, Countof(Country)* Value.

I am new to data.table and am impressed by its speed. I am particularly interested to know if there is an efficient data.table way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
DF[, 
  CJ(Category, Category, unique=TRUE)[if (.N == 1L) TRUE else V1 > V2][order(-V1, -V2)]
, by=Country]

   Country V1 V2
1:   India  A  A
2:  Canada  C  B
3:  Canada  C  A
4:  Canada  B  A
5: Ireland  C  A
```

*How it works*: Try running it in steps, with the second arg as:

- `CJ(Category, Category, unique=TRUE)`
- `CJ(Category, Category, unique=TRUE)[if (.N == 1L) TRUE else V1 > V2]`
- `CJ(Category, Category, unique=TRUE)[if (.N == 1L) TRUE else V1 > V2][order(-V1, -V2)]`

and read `?CJ`.

*Comment.* Generally, what you're asking for here is a bad idea in R and in data.table unless it's just for browsing the result. If you need to do further analysis, it is likely to be a lot more convenient with your data in long format instead of wide.